# Sequelize join multiple table and search

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have multiple table like products, category, subcategory and product images. Product has many product images also i want to add filter on category and subcategory with or condition but i am getting issue since product has many images.

```
return models.Products.findAndCountAll({
      attributes: { exclude: excludedAttributes }, // Exclude specified attributes
      include: [
       
        {
          model: models.Category,
          as: "categoryCategory",
          attributes: ["categoryName"]
        },
        {
          model: models.SubCategory,
          as: "subCategorySubCategory",
          attributes: ["subCategoryName"]
        },
        {
          model: models.ProductImages,
          as: "productImages",
          attributes: ["image"],
          // where: { status: 1 },
        },
       
      ],
      distinct:true,
      limit: parseInt(limit, 10),
      offset: parseInt(offset, 10),
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [
          {
            '$categoryCategory.category_name$': {
              [Op.like]: `%${searchKey}%`,
            },
          },
          {
            '$subCategorySubCategory.sub_category_name$': {
              [Op.like]: `%${searchKey}%`,
            },
          },
          {
            productName: {
                [Op.like]: `%${searchKey}%`,
            },
          },
          {
              sku: {
                  [Op.like]: `%${searchKey}%`,
              },
          },
        ],
      },
      order,
    })
```

Unknown column 'categoryCategory.category_name' in 'where clause'"

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this, subquery was getting generated to avoid subquery need to add this flas as below.

```
subQuery:false
```